# On Clicking getting value of an input field using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to pass an input field value via clicking a link using jquery. Here is my

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url().$row->file_path; ?>" target="_blank" class="download"><input type="hidden" name="file_id" id="file_id" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><?php echo $row->file_name; ?></a>
```

here is my jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".download").click(function(){

            //alert('<?php //echo site_url('admin_dashboard/data'); ?>');
            //return false;

            var data= document.getElementById('file_id');

            $.post("<?php echo site_url('admin_dashboard/data'); ?>",{ data:data},
                function(ajaxresult){
                $("#postrequest").html(ajaxresult);
            });
        });
    });
```

Is this the right way to pass a value to the other page via  clicking a link using jquery? If yes then where i am getting it wrong? if not what are the possible ways to do so. Kindly guide me through this...

Answer (score 0):

add `.value` here:

```
var data= document.getElementById('file_id').value;
```

---

As i see you are using ajax method in your script then you have to use `e.preventDefault()` to stop the page navigation:

```
$(".download").click(function(e){ // pass the event as arg
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the page to navigate
```

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to pass the DOM element itself, not the value... `document.getElementById('file_id').value` should give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to do that in your index.html
In your window scope right before

```
<script>
    var SITE_URL = <?= site_url() ?>, BASE_URL = <?= base_url() ?>;
</script>
</body>
```

Like this you don't need to write php in your html, and place your js in .js files to build better application.

for example , pass the argument to the new instance of your web app

You are also sending as data the HTML object and not his value.
To get is value use `.value` when assing the var;

Answer (score 0):

Grab the value rather than the element:

```
document.getElementById('file_id').value
```

Better, since you're using jQuery:

```
$('#file_id').val()
```